# Proguard error for missing inner class

Tags: android, android-proguard

I am configuring proguard for my project, but getting errors for anonymous classes like:

```
Warning:mypackage.editor.EditorCard$createView$1$1$2$2: can't find referenced class mypackage.editor.EditorCard$createView$1$1$2
```

I tried several methods like keeping everything in class, but nothing works. 
-keep class mypackage.editor.EditorCard.** { *; }

EditorCard extends AnkoComponent.

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it by

1. removing empty lambda blocks in the given class
2. changing signing version to v1 (Jar signature)
3. adding rule

   -keepclasseswithmembers class mypackage.editor.EditorCard { *; }
   -keep class * extends org.jetbrains.anko.AnkoComponent

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to your [proguard-rules.pro](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)

```
-keep com.alkymia.** { *; }
```

Comment: I added -keep class mypackage.player.ui.** { *; } but it gives same error.